# webgrid is empty after sorting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I have a webgrid defined within a partial view. (This is an MVC 4 project.) The webgrid isn't the only thing in the partial view, so the webgrid is bound to a List within the model of the partial view.

The grid populates and sorts as it should when a column header is clicked, but when I repopulate the grid by a call to an action method (via a form post set up using Ajax.BeginForm) and then click on a column header, the grid contents disappear. (The action method queries a database using search criteria provided on the form by the user.)

What could be causing this? How can it be resolved?

The partial view starts with:

```
@model DonationImport.Models.GiftWithSplits
```

The contents of the partial view are within a form designated by:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SearchConstit", "Batch", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "constitSearchArea" }))
```

The WebGrid is defined as follows:

```
@{
    var constitGrid = new WebGrid(source: Model.SearchResults, rowsPerPage: 100, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "constitGrid");                       
    <div style="overflow-x: scroll; width: 100%;">
        <div style="width: 1910px;">
            @constitGrid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id = "constitGrid" },
                columns: constitGrid.Columns(
                    constitGrid.Column(format: @<text><button onclick="selectConstituent('@item.Constituent_ID')" >select</button></text>, style: "searchResultsColumnWidth"), 
                    constitGrid.Column("Constituent_ID", header: "ConstitID", style: "searchResultsColumnWidth", format: @<text>@Html.ActionLink((string)item.Constituent_ID, "PriorGifts", new { constitID = item.Constituent_ID }, new { target = "Prior Payments" })</text>),
                        constitGrid.Column("IsActive", header: "Active", style: "searchResultsColumnWidth"),
                        constitGrid.Column("LastName", header: "Last", style: "searchResultsColumnWidth"),
                        constitGrid.Column("FirstName", header: "First", style: "searchResultsColumnWidth"),
                        constitGrid.Column("MiddleInitial", header: "M.I.", style: "searchResultsNarrowColumnWidth"),
                        constitGrid.Column("Spouse", header: "Spouse", style: "searchResultsColumnWidth"),
                        constitGrid.Column("EmailAddress", header: "E-mail", style: "searchResultsWideColumnWidth"),
                        constitGrid.Column("AddressLine1", header: "Address Line 1", style: "searchResultsWideColumnWidth"),
                        constitGrid.Column("City", header: "City", style: "searchResultsWideColumnWidth"),
                        constitGrid.Column("State", header: "State", style: "searchResultsColumnWidth"),
                        constitGrid.Column("Zip", header: "Zip", style: "searchResultsWideColumnWidth"),
                        constitGrid.Column("SearchResultsText", header: "Search Results", style: "searchResultsWideColumnWidth"),
                        constitGrid.Column("IsActivePledge", header: "Pledge", style: "searchResultsNarrowColumnWidth"),
                        constitGrid.Column("ReceiptWarning", header: "Receipt Warning", style: "searchResultsWideColumnWidth"),
                        constitGrid.Column("IsMember", header: "Mbr", style: "searchResultsNarrowColumnWidth")),
                        alternatingRowStyle: "altrow")
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

When one clicks on:

```
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
```

within the form, the action method called is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult SearchConstit(DonationImport.Models.GiftWithSplits g)
{           
    GiftWithSplits giftWithSplits = new GiftWithSplits(); // model (object) to be returned to the partial view

    // send back gift data which we are currently using
    giftWithSplits.GiftToVerify = g.GiftToVerify;

    // search using provided data
    string middleInitial = empty2null(g.GiftToVerify.SourceMiddleName);
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(middleInitial))
        middleInitial = middleInitial.Substring(0, 1); // just supply the initial, not the entire name

    string zip = empty2null(g.GiftToVerify.SourceZip);
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(zip))
        zip = zip.Substring(0, 5); // we want only the first 5 digits of the zip

    giftWithSplits.SearchResults = db.SearchDonor(null, g.GiftToVerify.DonationSourceCode, empty2null(g.SourceAcctMemo), null, empty2null(g.GiftToVerify.SourceLastName), 
        empty2null(g.GiftToVerify.SourceFirstName), middleInitial, empty2null(g.GiftToVerify.SourceAddress1),
        empty2null(g.GiftToVerify.SourceCity), empty2null(g.GiftToVerify.SourceState), zip, empty2null(g.GiftToVerify.SourceCountry),
        empty2null(g.GiftToVerify.SourceEmailAddress), empty2null(g.GiftToVerify.SourcePhone)).ToList();
    if (giftWithSplits.SearchResults.Count == 0)
    {
        SearchDonor_Result emptyResult = new SearchDonor_Result();
        emptyResult.Constituent_ID = "[None Found]";
        giftWithSplits.SearchResults.Add(emptyResult);
    }

    return PartialView("_ConstitSearch", giftWithSplits);
}
```

As you can probably tell, I am a beginner in this MVC approach.

Additional thoughts (added later)...

It seems the source of the problem is that the links generated by the WebGrid HTML help for the column headers are based on the URL related to the action method which produced the grid. When the grid is first displayed, the link is: /Batch/Verify/34?sort=FirstName&sortdir=ASC since the grid was build as a part of the entire Verify view (coming out of the Verify action method). But, when one searches for manually-entered search criteria, the grid is build from the SearchConstit action method which populates only a partial view, so the URL in the column header link is now: /Batch/SearchConstit?sort=FirstName&sortdir=ASC.

Also, the "Search" button is associated with a POST because it needs to pass data from the form fields to use as search criteria; whereas, the WebGrid column headers are using a GET, and apparently there is no way to force them to POST. So, the problem seems to boil down to how to pass the search criteria from the form fields without posting the form.

I can think of a possible solution using Session variables, but I'm hesitant to do it that way.

Another option might be to abandon the use of the WebGrid.

Any ideas?

Comment: Some more thoughts on the problem I posted above...

Comment: You should really use `Get` for the search button.  `Post` is typically meant for when you're changing something on the server (adding a record, etc).

Comment: If I use Get, then how do I pass in the search criteria from the form fields?

Comment: Query string!  You can use `form method="GET"` and that should sort it.  Anyway, sorry, I know that's not really the point of your question ...

Answer (score 0):

I found your question, when i was searching solution for same problem. I also faced same problem. I have used web grid to display data.
    I have used filter/pagination. I used text box for search in grid also.
    I am making post call for search. Webgrid was disappearing when i clicked filter  and paging button. I google a lot and didn't find any solution. Finally i found solution so thought of posting.
                       You need to use get ajax call instead of post call that will solve you problem. Do not use beginform post for search.

```
Index.cshtml is my main view. Here i m rendering partial view (_GridPartialView.cshtml). Index view has one webgrid and search text box.
I am using ajax call to search in webgrid. Ajax code is mention below.

**Index.cshtml:**

@model List<Login>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "User";
}


<h2 style="background-color: grey">User</h2>

<table>

    <tr>
        <td>
           <input type="text" id="txtSearch" placeholder="  Search..." onkeyup="Search()" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            @Html.ActionLink("Create New User", "CreateUser")</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>

                <div id="divPartialView">
                    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_GridPartialView.cshtml", Model)
                </div>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>


<script type="text/javascript">


    function Search() {
        var searchVal = $("#txtSearch").val();

        $.ajax({

            type: "GET",
            url: '/User/Search',
            data: { searchString: searchVal },
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#divPartialView').html(data);

            }

        });

    }
</script>

_GridUserPArtialView.cshtml: This is partial view used in index view.

@model List<Login>
  <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .webGrid { margin: 4px; border-collapse: collapse; width: 500px;  background-color:#FCFCFC;}
        .header { background-color: #C1D4E6; font-weight: bold; color: #FFF; }
        .webGrid th, .webGrid td { border: 1px solid #C0C0C0; padding: 5px; }
        .alt { background-color: #E4E9F5; color: #000; }
        .gridHead a:hover {text-decoration:underline;}
        .description { width:auto}
        .select{background-color: #389DF5}
    </style>

         @{
             var grid = new WebGrid(null, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 5, selectionFieldName: "selectedRow", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid");
        grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);
        grid.Bind(Model, autoSortAndPage: true, rowCount: Model.Count);}
       <div id="grid">
        @grid.GetHtml(

        tableStyle: "webGrid", mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,

                firstText: "<< First",
                previousText: "< Prev",
                nextText: "Next >",
                lastText: "Last >>",
                headerStyle: "header",
                alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
                selectedRowStyle: "select",
                columns: grid.Columns(

                grid.Column("UserName", "User Name", style: "description"),
                grid.Column("FirstName", "First Name"),
                grid.Column("LastName", "Last Name"),
                grid.Column("Action", format: @<text>

         @if (@item.LoginUserName != "administrator"){
                  @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.LoginUserName}) 
                  @Html.ActionLink("Delete","Delete", new { id = item.LoginUserId},new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this user?');" }) 

                 }
                            </text>,  style: "color:Gray;" , canSort: false)
         )) 

</div>

**UserController.cs**: This is Search action method inside. usercontroller. It is HTTPGET.

[HttpGet]
        public PartialViewResult Search(string searchString)
        {
            List<Login> userListCollection = new List<Login_User>();

            userListCollection = Login_User_Data.GetAllUsers();

            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
                {
                    Log.Info("UserController: Index() Started");
                    var searchedlist = (from list in userListCollection
                                        where list.FirstName.IndexOf(searchString,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >=0
                                        || list.LoginUserName.IndexOf(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
                                        || list.LastName.IndexOf(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
                                        select list
                                            ).ToList();

                    return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_GridPartialView.cshtml", searchedlist);

                }
                else
                {
                    Log.Info("UserController: Search(Login_User user) Ended");
                    return PartialView("_GridPartialView", userListCollection);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return PartialView("_GridPartialView", userListCollection);
            }

            Log.Info("UserController: Search() Ended");
        }



Hope this will help you. Let me know if you have any concern.
From: www.Dotnetmagics.com
```

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is pretty simple, you need to do a GET, whenever you sort or page the web gird, it will try to get data and hit the a HttpGet Action, this will work as follows:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult YourActionMethod()
    {
        return PartialView("YourView",YourModel);
    }
```

The best part is, upon sorting, the request will send a parameter named as "sortBy" too, you can use this here and decide what you want to do with the binded Model with the grid. You can inspect what URL the Sort header will hit by using the "Developer Tools" in your browser.

Note : By default the action method it would be hitting would be same as the controller name.